# How do I make a concluding sentence flow from the previous sentence?

Tags: technique, structure, non-fiction, flow, sentence-structure

*This question was flagged as being similar to another question of mine, so I have to clarify that this question pertains to how I should introduce the concluding sentence, whereas the other one pertains to which position a bridge sentence should occupy in a paragraph of the body text. These are not at all the same questions, especially since I'm already assuming that the paragraph contains a proper concluding sentence in the other question.*

I wonder how I should introduce a paragraph's concluding sentence without making it appear forced and detached from the supporting sentences. I have trouble with this since the supporting sentences often have already done enough to convince the reader of the topic sentence, so I have trouble writing concluding sentences that don't appear redundant, and it often feels abrupt if I insert a concluding sentence. Because of this, I have trouble beginning concluding sentences with anything other than "For these reasons", "Thus", or "Therefore" as well, and I also wonder if I should use such words to begin each conclusion.

This all pertains to the same problem: **how do I begin writing a concluding sentence?**

I have attempted to learn about this through simple sample paragraphs, but they've only taught me how to add a concluding sentence to simple paragraphs, if needed. Therefore, answers containing explanations that make use of difficult sample paragraphs would be of tremendous help.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide some examples. Why do you feel you need a concluding sentence in the first place? Especially if the other sentences have already "done enough." Generally, a paragraph is like a "mini" scene with discrete information. It's obvious from the structure itself that one ends and another begins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most effective way to transition from one paragraph to the next?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35645/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-transition-from-one-paragraph-to-the-next)

Comment: I understand why you may think those are the same questions, but you only do so because you may presuppose that concluding sentences can be replaced with bridge sentences, which I do not know (yet), hence the other question. Your comments have most likely prevented people from helping me out, especially when considering that this question even has upvotes, so you should answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the purpose of a concluding sentence is to tie the initial argument of the paragraph together, I like to think of my concluding sentence as the elevator pitch summary of my supporting arguments and how they support my main argument or point.

**On purpose of conclusions:** [here](https://msliewsclass.weebly.com/concluding-sentences.html) & [here](https://study.com/academy/lesson/concluding-sentence-definition-examples-starters.html)

To begin a writing a concluding sentence consider the paragraphs main point and supporting points. This doesn't necessarily have to correspond to each individual sentence, as one should look at the broader idea that the paragraph is trying to convey (details aren't critical to restate in a conclusion...and rather shouldn't!). From here I recommend constructing a sentence - maximum two sentences should ever be needed to conclude a paragraph - that summarizes these points using synonymous words and phrases (i.e. try not to repeat for verbatim what was previously said in the paragraph) that explicitly or implicitly support and refer to the purpose of the paragraph.

**Harvard University's Strategies:** [here](https://writingcenter.fas.harvard.edu/pages/ending-essay-conclusions)

> Because of this, I have trouble beginning concluding sentences with anything other than "For these reasons", "Thus", or "Therefore" as well, and I also wonder if I should use such words to begin each conclusion.

In regards to the above portion of the question, I agree that words such as *thus* and *therefore* can become quickly overused in conclusions and make the flow between supporting sentences and conclusion seem obvious. I encourage utilizing the technique of ending paragraphs with a transitional statement to the following paragraph and concluding essays with a strong final thought or question. By doing so the essay feels less formulaic and greatly contributes to the flow of the writing.

**On Writing Effective Conclusions:** [here](https://blog.writelab.com/blog/ending-your-essay-with-a-strong-conclusion)

Since we are on the topic on conclusions...make sure **not** to include new supporting points or details that weren't previously discussed. Think about the concluding sentence as the end to a party, you wouldn't introduce a friend to your group at the end of a party...so don't introduce new information in your conclusion.

**On good practices of conclusion writing:** [here](https://www.time4writing.com/writing-resources/writing-a-good-conclusion-paragraph/)

Answer (score 2):

Words That Sell helped me with transitions like this, but [this](http://www.studygs.net/wrtstr6.htm) list may help you for free.

If you're looking for something more specific, provide an example of what you mean and I'll take another crack at it.

I would also recommend reading a lot, especially the type of writing you're trying to do. Take note of how people who have mastered this craft do what you're trying to do.